# Apple Segmenter - is it working right?

Tags: iphone, video, streaming

I'm trying to get our video files (m4v) converted to the Apple http streaming and ran into some questions.

I have a file that is 6mb in size and when I pass it through the segmenter using all default settings the files that output add up to 32mb in size.  The last file is 17mb in size.

I'm not sure if that is how it is supposed to be but I'd rather use the smaller file if that is the case.

Anyone have any luck with this for vod content?

Comment: Read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859585/how-to-use-media-segmenter-for-split-video

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, there is an "optimise" setting in the install process that needs to be set.