# How to use Media Segmenter for split video?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have read many documents still very confused about `HTTP Live Streaming`.
But i am still trying for solution.. and i have convert my video in `.ts` format with `ffmpeg`.

Now i know that i have to split my video and have to create playlist with the use of `mediasegmenter`.
But i don't know where is `mediasegmenter` and how to use it to split video.
I am very new to this so sorry for this silly Question..

Any help would be appreciated..!!
Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Just curious, you said ...in mac but you don't tags in iphone and iOS but no mac or OSX

Comment: That was my mistake.. corrected it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here: [35703_streamingtools_beta.dmg](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=iphone/media_stream_segmenter_beta_20515/35703_streamingtools_beta.dmg) or go to http://connect.apple.com/ and search for "HTTP Live Streaming", or download from https://developer.apple.com/streaming/. Usage:

```
mediafilesegmenter -t 10 myvideo-iphone.ts
```

This will generate one .ts file for each 10 seconds of the video plus a .m3u8 file pointing to all of them.

Comment: i downloaded `HTTP Live Streaming Tool` and installed it. now i have  `sample.mp4` video on desktop. so i have to wright this code `mediafilesegmenter -t 10 sample.mp4` in terminal?? Am i right or doing something wrong..???

Comment: Yes, it should be on your path. Just type mediafilesegmenter. It is installed in /usr/bin/mediafilesegmenter.

Comment: Actually i can't see mediafilesegmenter in use/bin/..  Do you think it would be hidden..?? and i wright `mediafilesegmenter -t 10 sample.mp4` in terminal but it shows some options like `-b <url>  | --base-url=<url>    : base url (omit for relative URLs)
 -t <dur>  | --target-duration=<dur> : target duration for each segment ` and some other options...

Comment: Try downloading from: http://developer.apple.com/resources/http-streaming/ It should show on console if you type `ls -la /usr/bin/mediafilesegmenter`. If you type `mediafilesegmenter -t 10 sample.ts` it shouldn't show the usage screen, even if the video file sample.ts is missing.

Comment: i've downloaded from the same link.. if i type `ls -la /usr/bin/mediafilesegmenter` then i got `-rwxr-xr-x  1 jigar  wheel  1852172 Oct 28 03:07 /usr/bin/mediafilesegmenter` and if i type `mediafilesegmenter -t 10 Desktop/sample.mp4` then i get `Nov  2 2011 18:21:00.352: Finalized fileSequence0.ts
Nov  2 2011 18:21:00.357: segment bitrate 464285 is new max
Nov  2 2011 18:21:00.392: Finalized fileSequence1.ts
Nov  2 2011 18:21:00.404: segment bitrate 873824 is new max
Nov  2 2011 18:21:00.411: Finalized fileSequence2.ts` up to `Nov  2 2011 18:21:00.420: Finalized fileSequence74.ts`

Comment: That looks right, now you have to move the .ts files and m3u8 file to a web server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4684/discussion-between-jano-and-snhl)

Answer (score -3):

If you use FFMpeg, it's very easy to split files with it.
Don't use Media Segmenter.
Simply write something like this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i YourFile.mp4 -ss 00:10:00 -t 00:05:00 OutFile.mp4
```

where -ss 00:10:00 is time offset , -t 00:05:00 is duration of OutFile.mp4.
This will create OutFile.mp4 which contains 5 minute video(-t 00:05:00) of YourFile.mp4 
(from 00:10:00 to 00:15:00 of YourFile.mp4). 
Useful ?)

And also you can create .ASX playlist which is able to cast streams and is very simple.