# where can I download "media stream segmenter" from Apple

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming

I'm creating an AV app that will ultimately upload to a remote server, and need this segmenter to convert the live AV feed into files for buffering and upload.

Also:  any ideas for a better approach are welcome.

Comment: For live streaming you have to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592485/http-live-streaming

Comment: I have posted an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597884/iphone-ipad-downloading-and-playing-simultaneously/10601021#10601021 please check.. may be these links could help..

Comment: You can download the media segmenter tool from https://developer.apple.com/resources/http-streaming/ I am not sure this is watt you need..  I can post it as answer what you are looking for is this...:)

Comment: Read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859585/how-to-use-media-segmenter-for-split-video

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?=http%20live%20streaming%20tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple's documentation says: "One way to navigate to the tools is to log onto developer.apple.com, then use the search feature."

Fortunately I've found an easier way. Spoiler, you need to be a registered apple developer:

1) Go to https://developer.apple.com/

2) Go to the member center and log in

3) Click "SDKs"

4) Look for the "HTTP Live Streaming" link under "Media"

There will be a link on that page that will take you to the download page.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the link to the offical download for HTTP Live Streaming Tools from Apple.
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=http%20live%20streaming%20tools

This download includes:

- mediafilesegmenter
- mediastreamsegmenter
- mediastreamvalidator
- mediasubtitlesegmenter

It was found on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) on the right side under downloads.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can extract an old version of it from the 10.6.8 update:

http://www.ivanexpert.com/blog/2011/12/airplay-on-a-mac-play-any-video-through-your-apple-tv/